# Typescript: assign a readonly attribute in a function inside the constructor

Tags: typescript, constructor, readonly-attribute

I have a class with a readonly attribute that I define inside a `function`inside the `constructor`, the compiler issues an error I do not know how to solve:

```
    class TEST {
        public readonly desc: string;

        constructor() {
            const compute = () => {
                this.desc = "description"
            };
        }
    }
```

The compiler says: `"Cannot assign to "desc" because it is a readonly property"` but I thought that assigning the property inside the constructor will avoid this kind of errors.
Is it possible or do I have to change implementation?

Comment: But you are not assigning in the constructor, you are assigning in an arrow function that just happens to be defined in the constructor ..

Comment: Exactly! is there a way to get around this limitation? because I would like to declare the variable "readonly" but its value comes from the result of a function ...

Comment: It would be nice to know who downvote, but most important WHY :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a type assertion to get around it, the safest way it to use a mapped type that removes `readonly` from the type:

```
type Mutable<T> = {
    -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P];
};
class TEST {
    public readonly desc!: string;

    constructor() {
        const compute = () => {
            (this as Mutable<TEST>).desc = "description"
        };
    }
}
```

`readonly` is a rather weak modifier, so if you don't mind passing in `this` as a parameter, you can avoid the assertion:

```
class TEST {
    public readonly desc!: string;

    constructor() {
        const compute = (target: Mutable<TEST>) => {
            target.desc = "description"
        };
        compute(this)// works fine and not just because we are in teh constructor
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's Dragomir, you save my day!